# Implementing a non abstract class from an abstract class

Tags: java

A class called Patient contains 2 abstract methods namely getPatientdetails() and printPatientDetails. both methods should return nothing.
A class called OutPatient is a sub class of patient but is not abstract. Patient's details include PatientName(string) and DiseaseName(String). On outpatients, we also record the DateofVisit(String) and amount charged(Float).
Another class AdmittedPatient is also a sub class of patient calss and is not abstract. On admittedPatient, we also record wardName(string) and Bed Number(Int).

The challenge is to the Three classes and ensuring that these values are all captured from the user on runtime.

What would be the sudo code for this and then the explanation and java code for such an application to run?

Comment: I have the code but seems there is a problem, i've defined the 3 classes and the 1st one being abstract.import java.io.*;
public abstract class Patient {
public abstract String getPatientDetails();
public abstract String printPatientDetails();
}

Comment: The 2nd class is OutPatient import java.io.*;
public class OutPatient extends Patient
{
String PatientName;
String DiseaseName;
String DateOfVisit;
float AmountCharged;

} but this doesn't compile coz of the error that "OutPatient is not abstract and doesn't overide method "printPatientDetails"

Comment: @user2173809 Edit your question and post it there.

Comment: I've posted the question again here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999458/abstract-methods-and-classes